# Зачем такая конструкция?

Tags: javascript

Ниже в примере реализован, на сколько я понимаю, IIFE:

```
var myVar = function() {
          (0, _iterator.each)(myArray, function(index, column) {
                  //...some_iteration_code...
          })
};
```

Вопрос: Зачем **0** в первой скобке?

Comment: Конкретно это код выглядит как результат транспиляции примерно такого: `import { each } from iterator; …; each(…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется непрямой вызов функции или метода (indirect function call, можно погуглить для подробностей). Если вы просто заключите метод в скобки: `(_iterator.each)()`, скобки будут проигнорированы и получится обычный вызов метода, в котором `this` будет равно `_iterator`. Иногда нужно оторвать функцию от контекста вызова, и тогда в скобках функцию ставят после любого значения через запятую (это может быть `0` как символ того, что первый операнд до запятой не важен), в таком случае мы получаем последнее значение после запятой, ссылку на функцию, оторванную от контекста её вызова.

То есть `(0, _iterator.each)()` можно приравнять к такому виду намеренной потери контекста вызова:

```js
const func = _iterator.each;
func();
```

И это не IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), потому что Function Expression тут как раз нет. Хотя из-за сокращения шагов тут тоже есть "Immediately Invoked" и потому, наверное, срабатывает ассоциация.

Использоваться это может по-разному, в вашем случае нужно смотреть документацию или комментарии к коду.

Comment: обычно используется для `eval`, который при прямом вызове выполняется в локальной области видимости, а при непрямом - в глобальной. В остальных случаях обычно разницы нет

Comment: Да, вот тут есть объяснение и примеры: [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#description)

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение